# JAVA, cannot bypass the more specific direct super type

Tags: java, interface, default

I'm learning about interfaces. What happens here? and why I get a message:

> "Illegal reference to super type SomeInterface2, cannot bypass the
>   more specific direct super type interfejsy.SomeInterface3"

```
public interface SomeInterface1 {       
    public default void action(){
        System.out.println("default interface1 method");
    };

}

public interface SomeInterface2 {
    public default void action(){
        System.out.println("default interface2 method");
    };
}

public interface SomeInterface3 extends SomeInterface2{

    public default void action(){
        System.out.println("default interface3 method");
    }
}
```

...

```
public class ClassImplementingInterface implements SomeInterface1, SomeInterface2, SomeInterface3{

    //Every interface has action() method so we have to override it
    @Override
    public void action() {
        SomeInterface1.super.action();
        SomeInterface2.super.action(); //---- compiler error
        SomeInterface3.super.action();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> you can not access the default method of SomeInterface2,because
>   it's super interface of SomeInterface3.as implementing class,
>   ClassImplementingInterface only can visit its direct super interface's
>   default method.from a logical point of view,that
>   ClassImplementingInterface implements both interface SomeInterface2
>   and SomeInterface3,but SomeInterface2 is super interface,it seems
>   unreasonable,if you have to do so,try following program.

```
public interface SomeInterface1 {       
    public default void action(){
        System.out.println("default interface1 method");
    };
}

public interface SomeInterface2 {
    public default void action(){
        System.out.println("default interface2 method");
    };
}

public interface SomeInterface3 extends SomeInterface2{
     public default void action(){
         System.out.println("default interface3 method");
     }
     public default void action2(){
         SomeInterface2.super.action();
     }
  }

public class ClassImplementingInterface implements SomeInterface1,SomeInterface2,SomeInterface3{
    public void action() {
        SomeInterface1.super.action();
        SomeInterface3.super.action2();
        SomeInterface3.super.action();
    }
```

}